# Calculate mean data based on an index of different size

Tags: matlab

I need to calculate the mean over time series normalized to a certain event (time 0).
first column = time
second column = data of interest

```
A = [ -5 1 ; -4 2 ; -3 3 ; -2 4 ; -1 5 ; 0 6 ; 1 7 ; 2 8 ; 3 9 ; 4 10 ; 5 11 ];   

B = [ -3 7 ; -2 6 ; -1 5 ; 0 4 ;1 3 ; 2 2 ; 3 1 ];
```

result should like something like
C= [-5 NaN ; -4 NaN ; -3 5 ; -2 5 ; -1 5 ; 0 5 ; 1 5 ; 2 5 ; 3 5 ; 4 NaN ; 5 NaN ];

I have put all  data in one matrix so that the end of part B is filled with zeros. I thought about using find the index of the longest column and than mean over all columns +1 where the index was found. Is not working yet.

How can I do this as data are not the same length and index varies?
Thanks, Stefan

Comment: Please given an example of your desired result and of code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Could you interpolate between the time points?

Comment: I have added how the results should look. Still working on a loop with find index

Answer (score 2):

Generic solution for an arbitrary number of matrices, using [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
A = [ -5 1 ; -4 2 ; -3 3 ; -2 4 ; -1 5 ; 0 6 ; 1 7 ; 2 8 ; 3 9 ; 4 10 ; 5 11 ];
B = [ -3 7 ; -2 6 ; -1 5 ; 0 4 ;1 3 ; 2 2 ; 3 1 ];
matrices = {A, B}; %// put here as many matrices as needed
M = vertcat(matrices{:});
n = numel(matrices);
result = accumarray(M(:,1)-min(M(:,1))+1, M(:,2), [],...
    @(x) mean([x; NaN(n-numel(x),1)]), NaN);
```

This assumes that if all matrices have one intermediate value missing in the first column you also want that filled with `NaN`. If you want to skip those values you can use

```
result = accumarray(M(:,1)-min(M(:,1))+1, M(:,2), [],...
    @(x) mean([x; NaN(n-numel(x),1)]), inf);
result = result(~isinf(result));
```

Comment: This works way quicker than the above mentioned solution. Just need to look into it how it works (I do not know all of the function) and find the indexes which do correspond over all the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
[~,i1,i2] = intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1));
B_temp = [A(:,1) nan(size(A,1),1)];
B_temp(i1,:) = B(i2,:);
C = [A(:,1) mean([A(:,2) B_temp(:,2)],2)];
```

You can use what ever interpolation you want to have, but for two data points, `mean` should be okay. The output is:

```
C =

    -5   NaN
    -4   NaN
    -3     5
    -2     5
    -1     5
     0     5
     1     5
     2     5
     3     5
     4   NaN
     5   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for 2 data points this works fine. Does the same work for 7 or more data points? Matrix A to H with all different indices?

Comment: Well you can basically do: 1. find out which array is the largest. 2. Generate temporary matrices like `B_temp` for all of the remaining. 3. Add all temporary matrices into the `mean` for `C` (or `I`).

Comment: I have found the function mintersectm, adapted this function gives the same output as intersect. So I should be able to take it from here. Thanks Nemesis

Comment: Okay great. Good luck.